# Get file path of selected file in PHP CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the file path of a selected file in CodeIgniter. Mainly for validation purposes. I'm using `$_FILES['file']['name']`.But it only gives the file name. I want to get the full path.

As an example, I want to upload a file which is located in my desktop. So once I selected that file, I should be able to get the file path like this "C:\Desktop\file.doc". I want this because there are several file uploads in the same form and I want to validate those uploads before it goes to the database.

Comment: This is not possible in modern browsers for security reasons. It is arguably none of the web site's business what the original path was

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)